# ASP.Net Core 2.0 SignOutAsync deleting the wrong Cookie?

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

i have a ASP.net Core 2.0 MVC Application and experiencing a weird problem. When using *HttpContext.SignInAsync(...)* to SignIn a User in my AccountsControler.cs this creates a Cookie named ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application". When later using *HttpContext.SignOutAsync ()* to sign out the user, ASP.net Core decides to delete the cookie name "Identity.External" by setting this Cookie in the Response-Header to expire at the unix epoch.

Looks like i got something wrong with my CookieAuthentication. Anybody got an idea, where to look?

FunFact: Neither of both names is what i expected to see, since i configured a completely diffrent name for CookieAuthentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie (
    options => {
        options.Cookie.Name = "MyMagic.User";
    }
);
```

Comment: Those names come from AddIdentity.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/0ef83207d4a6337cf5eecbd5165721b806713ee2/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem seemed to be, that i used

```
service.AddAuthentication(...)
```

in this App. Looks like a ASP.net Core 1.0 migration artefact in my code.

After removing the explicit Cookie-Authentication, *SignInAsync()* and *SignOutAsync()* used the same cookie name.

Additionally, with

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts => {
   opts.Cookie.Name = "My.Cookie.User";
});
```

i was able to rename the cookie. :)

Comment: what are you using in Startup.cs if you're not using services.AddAuthentication(...)?

Comment: Well, as stated above: asp.net core 1.x used the `AddAuthenctication()` extension method while Asp.net Core 2.X use the `UseAuthentication()` extension method.

Mixing both extension methods into one startup.cs causes the trouble.